# Как убрать авто перенос тэга div?

Tags: html

Допустим, я напишу 2 тэга `div` (без `<br />`). Задам им фоновый цвет и размеры (обоим 10х10) и в результате они появятся один под другим, а мне надо, чтобы они были вместе - как это сделать?

Comment: Как на счет таблицы? одна строчка, 2 колонки, в колонках дивы...

Answer (score 3):

Потому что у тега DIV свойство block равно display. Тебе надо либо прописать стиль "display:block-inline", либо вместо DIV использовать SPAN

Answer (score 1):

**float** 
http://htmlbook.ru/css/float